# how to store array value in angularjs and then redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.messagearray = {};
$scope.messagewant = function(info) {
    $scope.messagearray = info;
    $location.path("/messagewant");
}
```

my code is redirecting without storing value in array

Comment: Where are you initialising ur array in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The code can be modified like this. Now info is passed to new location via query parameters.

```
$scope.messagearray = {};
$scope.messagewant = function(info) {
    $scope.messagearray = info;
    $location.path("/messagewant?info="+info);
}
```